# good ux design patterns to add/edit/remove entities in a mobile app?

Tags: forms, mobile, navigation, design-patterns, mobile-application

I'm looking for Android apps which have good entity management (add/edit/remove) UX.  The home page of my app displays a list of configured entity instances.  Now I need to give the user the ability to add/edit/remove these entity instances.  There could be a "Manage Entities" menu item in the left Drawer menu which would open a "Manage Entities" screen with the following design:

- The screen could display a search input supporting autosearch.
- The search input could display an Add button below it to support an Add scenario.
- Autosearch would return a list of matching entity list items below it on the screen.
- Each entity item in the list could have a checkbox on the left.  When a user selects one or more entity items a Delete button could be rendered at the bottom of the screen.
- Each entity list item could include an Edit button at the bottom.

These are just off the cuff ideas about how something like this could potentially work.  I'm looking for good Android apps which demonstrate a good implementation of these types of UX design patterns so I can decide the approach that I want to take in my own mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

I think the torrent app flud is a great example for your case. 1. there is search. 2 & 5 are for adding torrents, in this case you can add 2 different type of sources. When you press and hold one of the items in the list it pops up a checkbox left from every list item; you can delete one or multiple items using the "options" button and click remove item.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]             [image]

You can get some ideas from mail functionality, it gives pretty much all features that you are asking,

Swipe and long press gesture for delete and other operations is quite popular in mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

The design Patterns I could relate to your requirement is any app the manages contacts. In such requirements look at design patterns that meet these criteria.[image]